# Calling attributes in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, attributes, call

I'm a newbie in Objective-C. I have learned some others programs language before such as C++, C#, Java.In these language, syntax to call attributes or methods are object.attributes, object.methods and in Objective-C are object.attributes, [object methods]. Sometimes I can call [object attributes] in Objective-C but sometimes I can't. When I can use both, I wonder if there are any differences and which is better on these cases. And are we use the syntax [] on cases not the same in  Java, C#?

Example: I have a ObjectItem array. ObjectItem is a class have a BOOL-type attribute is isLive. I want to change value of the last item on this array.

Right: `((ObjectItem*)tempListDetail.lastObject).isLive=YES;`

Wrong: `[((ObjectItem*)tempListDetail.lastObject) isLive]=YES;` and I don't know why it wrong :(

Please tell(explain) me if you know, thanks. Sorry if I have any annoy or mistake :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you call a setter for `isLive` using the square bracket syntax is different: you replace the name of the getter (which coincides with the name of the attribute) with the name of the setter, like this:

```
[((ObjectItem*)tempListDetail.lastObject) setIsLive:YES];
```

When you use the dot syntax, Objective C compiler performs this little transformation for you, so the code ends up calling the same setter in both cases. There is no "better" or "worse" syntax here - pick one that you like better, and use it consistently throughout your program.

Answer (score 1):

Using dot notation allows you to set a property. Calling the method `isLive` only returns a value, to set the property you need to call the setter - `setIsLive:`